# UIImagePickerController : How do I add button and select photo

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios4

[image]

How do I add button and select photo. Please help and tell me how to solve

Comment: Help me, I'm in trouble kind of questions are not entertained in SO. Please show what you have tried so far, to get people interested in your question.

Comment: hi you. I just want to add button like on the iphone camera

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a CustomOverlayView. Then Config your picker something like this:

```
    overlay = [[CustomOverlayView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    overlay.delegate = self;
    picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    picker.toolbarHidden = YES;
    picker.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]){

        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    }
    else{
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    }
    picker.showsCameraControls = NO;
    picker.cameraOverlayView = overlay;
```

Answer (score -1):

This will work:

```
- (void)showImagePicker:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType)source{
    UIImagePickerController *imgPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imgPicker.sourceType = source;



    imgPicker.delegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:ipc animated:YES];
}
```

The button pressed action:

```
- (IBAction)chooseImage:(id)sender {

    [self showImagePicker:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];

}
```

And do this:

```
-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Or perform this code by the right actions

Comment: The question is about adding the little image preview in the bottom left corner.

Comment: Can you help me the example